# How do i use a button in my table to delete a specific row of data?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a `user class` in which i created a table of results from my `MYSQL` database. I want to have a button on each row of the table that a user can click to delete that certain row.

```
public function displayMyBooking() { //Added function

    $userid = $this->data()->id; //gets id of user currently logged in
    $query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT bookingdate, roomid, period FROM booking WHERE id = {$userid}"); //queries database for all bookings made with the id of the current user
    $amount = $query->count(); //returns amount of results
    $x=0;

    //create table
    $bookingtable = "<table style='width:100%' class='table'>";
    $bookingtable .= "<tr>";
    $bookingtable .= "<th>Room ID</th>";
    $bookingtable .= "<th>Period</th>";
    $bookingtable .= "<th>Booking Date</th>";
    $bookingtable .= " </tr>";

for($x=0; $x<$amount; $x++) { //loop through and output data into table according to amount of results returned
    $bookingtable .= "<tr>";
    $bookingtable .= "<td>" . $query->results()[$x]->roomid. "</td>";
    $bookingtable .= "<td>" . $query->results()[$x]->period. "</td>";
    $bookingtable .= "<td>" . $query->results()[$x]->bookingdate. "</td>";
    $bookingtable .= "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'></td>";
    $bookingtable .= "</tr>";
    $bookingtable .= "";
}
return $bookingtable;       
}
```

This function is accessed on my page simply by

```
       <?php
            $table = $user->displayMyBooking();
            echo $table;
        ?>
```

Each booking (i am developing a room booking system) has a unique composite primary key which i created with the date booked, period booked, user ID etc. How can i use the delete button included in my table to delete that specific row?

Comment: You need to write a CRUD; Create, Read, Update, Delete. https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `<form>` being used in `displayMyBooking()` method, so there's no point using a lone submit input element there. Instead, simply change this statement

```
$bookingtable .= "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'></td>";
```

to this:

```
$bookingtable .= "<td><a href='delete.php?roomid=" . $query->results()[$x]->roomid . "'>Delete</a></td>";
```

---

Later, on **delete.php** page, you can access *that* particular row/roomid using `$_GET` superglobal, like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['roomid']) && (!empty($_GET['roomid']) || $_GET['roomid'] == 0)){
    $roomid = $_GET['roomid'];

    // perform delete operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<button name="delete_row' value="1234">Delete</button>
```

or create form for each row e.g.

```
<form action="delete.php">
<input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="1235" />
<td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
<input
```